# How do you set a one-off access checker on a route?

Tags: 8, routes

As far as we can tell, the "Simplified custom access checker" section of the [handbook](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/routing-system/access-checking-on-routes) is outdated. The entirety of [`CheckProvider`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Access!CheckProvider.php/class/CheckProvider/8.1.x) seems to be service oriented and this is the provider which has the `$route->setOption('_access_checks', $checks);` call. In turn, `AccessManager::check` has a `$checks = $route->getOption('_access_checks') ?: array();` call. There's nothing which would accommodate one-off checkers like the handbook page suggests:

```
requirements:
  _custom_access: '\Drupal\example\Controller\ExampleController::access'
```

and based on our debugging, this is indeed not working. What is the current way, if any, to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The handbook is correct. The access is handled by services. The normal way to implement a custom access check is to define a service in **mymodule.services.yml**. See this example from the core book module:

```
  access_check.book.removable:
    class: Drupal\book\Access\BookNodeIsRemovableAccessCheck
    arguments: ['@book.manager']
    tags:
      - { name: access_check, applies_to: _access_book_removable }
```

And then use this in routing:

```
_access_book_removable: 'TRUE'
```

Here you can choose your own arbitrary naming schema.

As described in the handbook, if you want to simplify this, you can reuse the service `access_check.custom`, which is already defined in **core.services.yml**:

```
  access_check.custom:
    class: Drupal\Core\Access\CustomAccessCheck
    arguments: ['@controller_resolver', '@access_arguments_resolver_factory']
    tags:
      - { name: access_check, applies_to: _custom_access }
```

Then you have to use `_custom_access:` for the route. You can not use something like `_my_module_access`: as before, the key must match the tag in the service definition.

The first solution puts the complete logic of the access check in a service and makes it reusable and self-explanatory. If you only need the access code in one route and want to place the access code in the controller class the second method provides a shortcut.